# Multiple excel sheet data mapped to a single set of Examples in Specflow Scenario Outlines

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am using Specflow in C#, along with the SpecFlow+ Excel plugin to pull data from an excel spreadsheet.

I know that in scenarios, I can pull in data from a sheet into examples by using the tag `@Source:MySheet.xlsx:Sheet1`. However, I would like to have multiple sets of examples from different sheets be pulled into the one `Scenario Outline`. Eg, something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Process inputs
    Given the first set of inputs:
    |  a  |  b  |  c  |
    | <a> | <b> | <c> |
    And the second set of inputs:
    |  d  |  e  |  f  |
    | <d> | <e> | <f> |
    When I submit the data
    Then magic happens

@Source:MySheet.xlsx:Sheet1
Examples: Main data
    | a | b | c |

@Source:MySheet.xlsx:Sheet2
Examples: Other data
    | d | e | f |
```

However when I try to compile, I get the following error:

`Generation error: The example sets must provide the same parameters.`

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or will I have to squeeze all of my inputs into the one Sheet?

Comment: As you have 6 parameters in your Scenario outline, you have to define all of them in the examples to get this to work.

Comment: I see. in my actual case, I have about 45 parameters in total, and I wanted to break them down into different groups/sheets in the spreadsheet, to make it easier to maintain

Comment: I would not have data from two separate sources even if I could. Each test should verify one thing, not 45. Seems like these tests are too complex. Just my opinion.

Comment: your question is badly titled  IMHO. You don't want multiple sets of examples, you want your example data to come from multiple sheets in your spreadsheets. I don't believe this feature is supported and I'm struggling to see how you might specify that with a decent syntax. You can't really have it work as you have outlined above as this syntax implies multiple sets of incomplete examples

Comment: Good point. I'l re-title it